# Is a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ necessarily measurable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a subset that is simply connected as a topological space.

Is $S$ necessarily Lebesgue measurable?

Is it necessarily Borel measurable?

What's the proof?

(Intuitively I think the answer should be "yes" to both, but I would have no idea how to prove. I mean, $S$ could be pretty wild.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $V\subseteq [0,1]$ be a nonmeasurable subset of $\Bbb R$, such as the Vitali set, and consider the "comb" $(V\times[0,1])\cup ([0,1]\times\{0\})$, which is a simply connected nonmeasurable subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

To see that this set is nonmeasurable remember that if $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal B,\nu)$ are two measure spaces then for a measurable $E\subseteq X\times Y$ we have that the slices $E_y=\{x\in X\mid (x,y)\in E\}$ are $\mu$-measurable for $\nu$-almost every $y$ and that the slices $E_x=\{y\in Y\mid (x,y)\in E\}$ are $\nu$-measurable for $\mu$-almost every $x$. If you slice this set in the right direction you'll get Vitali sets for all slices except a single one, so it cannot be measurable.

To see that this set is simply connected is best to just draw it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer please? Why is $V \times [0,1] \cup [0,1] \times \{0\}$ simply connected and non-measurable? Moreover, what does the last $\{0\}$ do exactly? Why is it there?

Comment: the last $\{0\}$ is part of a product, $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ and it's there to get the backbone of the comb in place (which makes it all simply connected).  If you draw the set, as suggested in the answer, you'll see that each point of the Vitali set provides a 'tooth' of the comb along the interval $[0,1]$ and you can walk along the backbone and up and down each tooth

Comment: My edit was merely to add some brackets to the def'n of the "comb" to make it easier to read it.

Comment: @stressedout - in case further elaboration is useful: Allesandro Codenotti's answer is set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus to specify points you have to specify both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. The $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ is the set of points with $x$ coordinate in $[0,1]$ and whose $y$ coordinate is $0$. Without the $\times\{0\}$, it's not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: +1 Beautiful! (And, accepted.) Also, in order so that this question/answer pair contains a formal proof of simple connectedness: the set given is homotopy equivalent to an interval, since it deformation retracts to $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ via the family of maps $(x,y)\mapsto (x,(1-t)y)$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: p.s. Alessandro did you really just recommend that we draw a Vitali set? :)